# Handlebars won't loop over my Backbone.js Collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a Backbone app where I'm attempting to populate a collection using a JSON file. I want to generate a list of "titles" from the JSON to eventually turn into a menu. 
Everything is going well, except that Handlebars won't loop (each) over my collection to render the list.

The relevant view:

```
var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: Handlebars.compile(
    '<ul>' +  
    '{{#each items.models}}<li>{{attributes.title}}</li>{{/each}}' +
    '</ul>'
),

initialize: function  () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
},   

render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(items));
    return this;
}

});
```

The model and collection:

```
var Magazine = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot:"/items",
defaults: {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    pubDate: '1/1',
    image: ''
}
});
var MagazineMenu= Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: 'title',
    model: Magazine,
    url: "/items"
});
```

The router:

```
var MagazineRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
   "" : "listPage",
   "titles/:id" : "showTitle"
}, 
initialize: function  () {
    this.magazineModel = new Magazine();
    this.magazineModel.fetch();


    this.magazineView = new MagazineView({
        model: this.magazineModel
    });

    this.magazineCollection = new MagazineMenu();
    this.magazineCollection.fetch();

    this.menuView = new MenuView({collection: this.magazineCollection});
},

showTitle: function(id) {

    this.magazineModel.set("id", id);
    $("#theList").html(this.magazineView.render().el);
},

listPage : function() {
    $('#theList').html(this.menuView.render().el);
}
});

var router = new MagazineRouter();

$(document).ready(function() {
    Backbone.history.start(); 
});
```

And finally the JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": "screamingzebras",
    "url": "screamingzebras",
    "title": "Screaming Zebras",
    "pubDate": "2/1",
    "image": "screamingzebras.jpg"
},
{
    "id": "carousellovers",
    "url": "carousellovers",
    "title": "Carousel Lovers",
    "pubDate": "3/1",
    "image": "carousellovers.jpg"
},
{
    "id": "gardenstatuary",
    "url": "gardenstatuary",
    "title": "Garden Statuary",
    "pubDate": "4/1",
    "image": "gardenstatuary.jpg"
},
{
    "id": "sombreromonthly",
    "url": "sombreromonthly",
    "title": "Sombrero Monthly",
    "pubDate": "1/1",
    "image": "sombreromonthly.jpg"
}
]
```

When I run this in a browser, I get no errors in the console. If I `console.log(this.collection)` just before the call to `this.$el.html(this.template(items));` in the view, I can see the collection with a models attribute that is properly populated from the JSON.
When I look at the Elements panel in Chrome dev tools, I can see that it is generating everything up to and including the `<ul>` tag. That leads me to believe that I'm just missing a key logic point that is getting the Handlebars each function to actually loop over the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

1. `items` isn't defined anywhere so your `render` is really saying `this.template(undefined)`.
2. Even if you did have a local variable called `items`, your Handlebars template won't know that you've called it `items` so it won't know that `{{#each items.models}}` should iterator over it.

Presumably your `items` is really supposed to be the view's `this.collection` and your `render` should look more like this:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection));
    return this;
}
```

That should solve problem **1**. You can fix problem **2** in two ways:

1. Change the template to refer to the right thing.
2. Change how you call `this.template` so that `items` is associated with the right thing.

The first option would use the above `render` and a template that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each models}}
        <li>{{attributes.title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The second option would leave your template alone but change `render` to use:

```
this.$el.html(
    this.template({
        items: this.collection
    })
);
```

Another option would be to use `this.collection.toJSON()` to supply data to the template, then `render` would use:

```
this.$el.html(
    this.template({
        items: this.collection.toJSON()
    })
);
```

and then template would be:

```
<ul>
    {{#each items}}
        <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks... but I tried all three of those solutions, and all three result in the same thing: nothing. No output other than the <ul>s, no errors.
I think the problem is this: if I do console.log(this.collection) within the render function, I'm seeing:
r {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _listenId: "l4", _events: Object…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_listenId: "l4"
length: 4
models: Array[4]
__proto__: s

So the initial output says length is zero, which would explain why each isn't looping. But the expanded output says length is 4, and then should that there are 4 models in there.

Comment: Backbone's `fetch` is an AJAX call so the collection will be empty right after you say `c.fetch()`. Then later, the server will respond and the collection will be populated. The console holds a live reference to the collection so it will reflect the change when the AJAX call gets around to finishing. Try `fetch({ reset: true })` and binding your `render` call to a reset event: `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)`.

Comment: Well, that worked ... for a minute. As soon as I tried to navigate to another item, I started getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenId' of undefined`. Now, thats' all I can get - my other view, which had been working fine, is returning the same error. Googling seems to imply it's a timing issue, but none of the solutions elsewhere really apply to my very simple app. Grrr.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious (but your `$("#theList").html()` calls will eventually screw up your view events: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21565759/479863). Can you replicate the problem on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com ?

Comment: I had the same error, just fyi make sure you're passing in a "collection" and not a "model". eg:

    app.forecastHourly = new app.views.ForecastHourly({
        el: 'hourly',
        **collection**: hourlyList
    });